# Insert new value in Dictionary at specific point

Tags: tcl

I would like insert a new value in my dictionary not at the end , but at a given position , like `linsert` function, it's important for me to keep the order of my dictionary.
My new value : `dict set mydict ford wheels 4` 
 My dictionary :

```
set mydict {mercedes {wheels 4} opel {wheels 4}}
```

I would like this result :`mercedes {wheels 4} ford {wheels 4} opel {wheels 4}`
 
and not this :`mercedes {wheels 4} opel {wheels 4} ford {wheels 4}`

Comment: What's stopping you from using `linsert`?

Comment: To tell the truth I did not try...

Comment: Please try. Almost everything in Tcl is a string, and one could consider lists and dicts, for instance, to just be convenient ways to structure those strings. This means that if one looks like the other, chances are the commands you use on will likely also work on the other. Here, one could say that a dict is a special list; your current dict looks like a list with 4 elements and you need to insert 2 elements at index 2.

Comment: ok , I think I found `linsert $mydict 2 ford {wheels 4}`, I thought there was a better way like `dict insert` , thank you Jerry for the explanations

Comment: dicts were not meant to be sorted from the start, they are only a storage structure after all. for display purposes, one could always use `dict keys` with some sorting function if necessary to print the dict key/values in the desired order. So inserting at a specific position had no purpose.

Comment: The first version of dicts were not ordered at all, and could be reordered by the system at will (usually when the hash table was rebuilt, the conditions for which are non-trivial). That turned out to be annoying, so as part of a push to make all standard types have consistent serializations (fixing floating point serialization was a _lot_ harder; that stuff is subtle!) we fixed the iteration order of dicts to be the most universally useful one: order of first insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order maintained by dictionaries is that of first insertion; where the key is not already in the dictionary, it always goes at the end. (It had to go somewhere consistent.) There's no operation to put it elsewhere.

But you can make one! The trick is to know that dicts can be “type-punned” to lists efficiently. Indeed, dicts deliberately have the same formatting rules as lists (subject to the constraint that there must be an even number of elements, and duplicate keys get dropped). That means you can use `linsert` to do the tricky bit (assuming you use numeric indices and not `end`-relative ones).

```
proc dict_set_at {dictionaryVar index key value} {
    upvar 1 $dictionaryVar d
    if {[dict exists $d $key]} {
        dict set d $key $value
    } else {
        set d [linsert $d [expr {$index * 2}] $key $value]
    }
    return $d
}

# Demo code
set mydict {mercedes {wheels 4} opel {wheels 4}}
dict_set_at mydict 1 ford {wheels 4}
puts $mydict
#  mercedes {wheels 4} ford {wheels 4} opel {wheels 4}
```

One key caveat: this is not as efficient as plain old `dict set`. But it does work.